# two HashMap iteration

Tags: java, data-structures

I have two HashMaps and I can iterate both hashmaps with following code

```
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String firstVal = pairs.getValue();
}

Iterator it2 = mp2.entrySet().iterator();
while (it2.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs2 = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String SecondVal = pairs2.getValue();
}

myFunction(firstVal, SecondVal)
```

Is there anyway to iterate two hashmaps at the same time without using two loops?

Currently, I have a method that accepts two parameters and each parameter value is stored in first and second hashmap. I have to iterate first hash then second to get values. I think there must be a good way to do it but I don't know :(

P.S: there could be some errors in above code as this is just an example to explain my problem. Each iterator is a method in original program and accept one parameter. I couldn't copy past real time functions as they are HUGE !

Comment: does first and second value have the same key?

Comment: no both Map have different values :(

Comment: How are they correlated?

Comment: Yes then how are they being co-related? Maps doesn't retain the insertion order like List so better post your entire code or specify the requirement at a high level so that we can offer better help

Comment: @Pangea, Not true...`LinkedHashMap` does it by insertion order.

Comment: You are right. I am trying to convey a message to him saying that the Map implementation he uses matters as there seems to be no correlation on the two maps...hope you get the point ;-)

Comment: Well, each hashmap contains document list and I am performing some calculations. I get value from one hashmap and multiply by all values from second hashmap. I hope it helps.

Comment: can u give an example of data (including key and value) in each map and also an example calculation

Comment: It sounds like you want to iterate the second map once for each entry in the first map (in which can you'd want 2 loops). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Pangea - WRONG - Some MAPs are ordered, some are not = HashMaps arent ordered, TreeMaps are ordered (see Comparator)

Comment: mP- I am aware of these. For that matter, TreeMap doesn't maintain the insertion order. it maintains the "natural" order of the keys while LinkedHashMap maintains the insertion order. I am just trying to make him think in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code looks good. Just use while loop as inner and outter loops to iterate on both HashMaps. In second while loop, you can call your function to perfrom whatever you want.

```
while loop (iterate first hashmap)
    second while loop(iterate second hashmap)
         call your function here and pass values
```

Answer (score 3):

Put values of 2 maps into a list, then loop the list:

```
//Merge 2 values of maps to a list
List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<String>();
mergedList.addAll(map1.values());
mergedList.addAll(map2.values());

int size = map1.size() < map2.size() ? map1.size() : map2.size();
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
    myFunction(mergedList.get(i), mergedList.get(map1.size() + i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Map.Entry pairs;
    String firstValue = null;
String secondValue = null;
    while(it.hasNext() || it2.hasNext()){
     if (it.hasNext()){
      pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
      firstValue = pairs.getValue();
     }
     if (it2.hasNext(){
      pairs = (Map.Entry)it2.next();
      secondValue = pairs.getValue();
     }
     if (firstValue != null && secondValue != null){
       yourMethodHere();
       firstValue = null;
       secondValue = null;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to pass one value at a time and inside the loop if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
if (mp.size() != mp2.size()) {
    throw SomeException("mismatched parameters");
}
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
Iterator it2 = mp2.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String firstVal = pairs.getValue();
    Map.Entry pairs2 = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String secondVal = pairs2.getValue();
    myFunction(firstVal, secondVal);
}
```

Note that doing a parallel iteration over the entries in a pair of a HashMaps is dodgy.  The *only* case where the entries of the HashMaps will "line up" by keys is if the two HashMaps have identical keys with the same hashcodes, and they were populated in the same order starting from newly allocated HashMaps.

So therefore, I think that you really need to do something like this.

```
if (mp.size() != mp2.size()) {
    throw SomeException("mismatched parameters");
}
Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    String firstVal = pairs.getValue();
    String SecondVal = mp2.get(pairs.getKey());
    myFunction(firstVal, SecondVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot iterate two maps in one loop unless they have same set of keys. I don't know how you find `firstVal` and `SecondVal`, it seems little ambiguous. Maybe you could get the those two values by `Map.get()`?

Answer (score 0):

If the Map objects are themselves parallel, then perhaps the better solution would be to create a custom Class instead of using a Map.  One can guarantee the iteration order in Maps as has already been mentioned in certain util Objects (another one is LinkedHashMap).  This does not give the developer license though to use the objects as if they were arrays or lists.